# how to fix: code: -2019, msg: 'Margin is insufficient.' #899

Tags: javascript, node.js, binance, binance-api-client

I am trying to open a simple short position on coin-m futures

Here's the code:

```
const Binance = require('node-binance-api');

const binance = new Binance().options({
APIKEY: 'some api key',
APISECRET: 'some secrets',
'family': 4,
});

let temp = async () => {
//console.info( await binance.universalTransfer("MAIN_CMFUTURE","XRP",10) );
console.info(await binance.deliveryMarginType("XRPUSD_PERP", "CROSSED"));
console.info(await binance.deliveryLeverage("XRPUSD_PERP", 1));
console.info(await binance.deliveryMarketSell("XRPUSD_PERP", 70, { positionSide: "SHORT"}));
}

temp();
```

I have also checked the balance, here is the result:

```
[Object: null prototype] { 
     asset: 'XRP', 
     walletBalance: '104.91600000', 
     unrealizedProfit: '0.00000000', 
     marginBalance: '104.91600000', 
     maintMargin: '0.00000000', 
     initialMargin: '0.00000000', 
     positionInitialMargin: '0.00000000', 
     openOrderInitialMargin: '0.00000000', 
     maxWithdrawAmount: '104.91600000', 
     crossWalletBalance: '104.91600000', 
     crossUnPnl: '0.00000000', 
     availableBalance: '104.91600000', 
     updateTime: 1696236724456 
}
```

Why is the margin insufficient and how can i fix this error?

Comment: Why do you think this is a coding error and not that your current account has an insufficient margin to make this trade?

Comment: I don't think it is a coding error, precisely. I just write what i see: i have balance (xrp), and i can't open a position. It may be my lack of trading skills, thus i asked here

Comment: "It may be my lack of trading skills, thus i asked here" - but then this is the wrong place. This is a knowledge base for programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, there is a multiplier factor.

You should think of your balance as a (your balance / multiplier factor)

multiplier factor is how much coins there are in 10 usd, for xrp it is 19 (at the time of writing)

so when my balance is 104 xrp coins, i have to think of them (104 / 19) ~ 5

Hope that explains it and helps someone!